# how to sum observations in SAS by groups?

Tags: sas

I have an example of a dataset in the following manner

```
data have;
input match percent;
cards;
0   34
0   54
0   33
0   23
1   60  
1   70
1   70
1   70
;
```

Essentially I want to sum the observations that are associated with `0` and then divide them by the number of `0`s to find the average.
e.g 34+54+33+23/4 then do the same for `1`'s

I looked at PROC TABULATE. However, I don't understand how to carry out this procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very easily using `proc summary` or `proc means`.

```
proc summary data=have nway missing;
class match;
var percent;
output out=want mean=;
run;
```

You can also output a variety of other statistics using these procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this in SAS.  I would use `PROC SQL`

```
proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select match, 
       mean(percent) as percent
   from have
   group by match;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `proc means` and you will the mean plus a bunch of other stats:
more examples [here](http://galsterhome.com/stats/Tutorial/SAS11.htm) for `proc means`.

```
proc means data=have  noprint;
by match;
output out=want ;
```

Output:

[image: output mean]